# Stop AvAudioPlayer in other View iOS

Tags: ios, audio, view, avaudioplayer

I would like to stop the audio with AvAudioPlayer but when another view dissapear, There are two views:

The problem is that when view2 disappear, the audio doesn't stop... How I should do?

**View1.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender;
```

**View1.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     [self playSound];

}

- (void) playSound
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"simpsonsTheme"
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];
    NSError *error;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    //[self.audioPlayer play];
    [self playAudio:audioPlayer];

}

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    [audioPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender {
    [audioPlayer stop];
}
```

And **View2.m**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    view1 = (View1 *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [view1 stopAudio:view1.audioPlayer];
    }
```

In the View2 I import the View1 to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app delegate is not a view controller. Maybe you want `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController`.

As you've seen, that's fragile. Instead of having pointers between your viewcontrollers, you could use have looser coupling and use a "stop" `NSNotification`. It may even be useful elsewhere in your application.

Define

```
NSString *StopPlayingVideoNotification = @"StopPlayingVideo";
```

So both views can see it, so put `extern NSString *StopPlayingVideoNotification;` in one of your header files.

In View1.m's init:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopAudio:) name:StopPlayingVideoNotification object:nil];
```

Add a dealloc to View1:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:StopPlayingVideoNotification object:nil];
}
```

In View2.m

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:StopPlayingVideoNotification object:self];
}
```

Comment: Do StopPlayingVideoNotification = @"..." where ever you like, but extern NSString *StopPlayingVideoNotification must be in a .h file included by both .m files. You could define StopPlayingVideoNotification in view1.m and put the extern in view.h. You need to add the dealloc call to view1.